# I can't run programs double clicking on them

Tags: dll, console, exe, clion, libstdc++

I'm using CLion to code and run my C++ programs, but sometimes I don't like its built-in console for many reasons.

The problem is that if I try to launch the executable double clicking on it, two errors pop up. They say libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll and libstdc++-6.dll are missing... Is there any easy way to fix this?

(I know this has already been asked in another question but I couldn't find any easy ways)

Answer (score 0):

Am I right that you are using MinGW toolchain? If so please try to add *mingw_installation_path/bin* to your %PATH%.

It's definitely problem with missed dll in your Path.

Comment: You are indeed! Could you tell me how to do it?

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/284342/what-are-path-and-other-environment-variables-and-how-can-i-set-or-use-them